# Can't get uuid value in email body in django

Tags: django, authentication, email, uuid, email-verification

I have authentication app with email verification in it. I send an email like this:
If registration form is valid then we save the form(create user) and set his token to `uuid.uuid4`.

```
class customer_register(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = CustomerSignUpForm
    template_name = 'authentication/customer_register.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        user.token = str(uuid.uuid4)
        subject = 'Verify your account | Zane'
        message = f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/verify/{user.token}/"
        send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            'from@example.com',
            ['to@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

In my *mailtrap.io* email arrives but it has some weird body:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/verify/<function uuid4 at 0x103f32040>/

Answer (score 1):

Please use `str(uuid.uuid4())` instead of `str(uuid.uuid4)`